# vs codeでのjava

Tags: java, vscode

vs codeでjavaを実行できるようにしようと思ったのですがJava Extension Packをインストールし、jdkのpathを設定しても「Build failed」と表示されて実行できません。助けていただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 3):

情報が足りなさすぎるので、色々確認させていただきたいののと、想定されるエラー及び解決策を記載します。
また、デバッグコンソールに表示された内容を記載して頂ければすぐに完結できる問題かと思いますので、「Build failed」と共に表示されるメッセージを記載頂けるともっと簡潔に解決が可能です。

**○確認事項**
VSCodeを使用せずコンソールなどでコンパイルするとどうなりますでしょうか？
手順としては以下の通りになります。（Windowsの場合です）

1. コマンドプロンプト起動（Windowsキー + R → cmd入力）
2. コードがあるフォルダまで移動（cd c:\work\20190222 など）
3. コンパイル（javac Hoge.java）

   - この際に設定したjdkのパスを直接指定するとなお良いです。（"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\javac.exe" Hoge.java）

**○予想されるエラー原因その1（パスの指定が誤っている）**
設定の確認もさせてください。
JDKのPATHを設定とは以下で良いでしょうか？

```
"java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.2"
```

※Windowsの場合区切りは「\」を2つ記載する必要があります。
※binまで記載する必要はありません
※JREのPATHではなく、JDKのPATHである必要があります。

**○予想されるエラー原因その2（ファイル名とclass名があっていない）**
Javaではファイル名とClass名が一致している必要があります。
ファイル名がHoge.javaならば、class名はHogeとなります。

---

以下で実行が可能でしたので、ご自分の状況と比べてみてください。

1. 拡張機能「Java Extension Pack」を追加
2. VSCodeを再起動
3. 設定に以下を追加
4. Hoge.javaを作成（コードは以下の通り）
5. mainの上に表示される「Run」を押下

---

```
"java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.2"
```

---

```
public class Hoge {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```